# Promise.all returning undefined

Tags: javascript, promise, jsonp, es6-promise

I have wrapped jsonp request in a promise, and I am making a series of API calls, which I would like to further process once they all have been resolved.

```
 var users = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas", "twitchpresents"]

Promise.all(users.map(function(user){
    var url = "https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/users/" + user;
    return jsonp(url);
})).then(function(arr){
    console.log(arr);
})
```

It returns an array of promises whose PromiseValue is undefined, which doesn't permit me to further process the values.

My JSONP promise wrapper is here:

```
 var count = 0;

var jsonp = function(url, options) {
    options = options || {};

    var prefix = options.prefix || '__jp';
    var param = options.param || 'callback';
    var timeout = options.timeout ? options.timeout : 15000;
    var target = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0] || document.head;
    var script;
    var timer;
    var cleanup;
    var cancel;
    var promise;
    var noop = function() {};

    // Generate a unique id for the request.
    var id = prefix + (count++);

    cleanup = function() {
        // Remove the script tag.
        if (script && script.parentNode) {
            script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
        }

        window[id] = noop;

        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    };

    promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (timeout) {
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                cleanup();
                reject(new Error('Timeout'));
            }, timeout);
        }

        window[id] = function(data) {
            cleanup();
            resolve(data);
        };

        // Add querystring component
        url += (~url.indexOf('?') ? '&' : '?') + param + '=' + encodeURIComponent(id);
        url = url.replace('?&', '?');

        // Create script.
        script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = url;
        target.parentNode.insertBefore(script, target);

        cancel = function() {
            if (window[id]) {
                cleanup();
                reject(new Error('Canceled'));
            }
        };

    });

    return {
        promise: promise.then(function(data){
            var user = {
                name: data.name,
                logo: data.logo,
            };


           userData.push(user);
        }),
        cancel: cancel
    };
}
```

I can push the result from within the individual API call, but is there a way of accessing the values from Promise.All?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't return anything from promise. Try this:

```
promise: promise.then(function(data){
  var user = {
    name: data.name,
    logo: data.logo,
  };

  userData.push(user);

  return user; // <-- pass data further
}),
```